# How to user input here?

Tags: java

Here is the below code:

```
import comp102x.IO;

public class CalculatorEx01 {
    public static void multiply() {

// Please write your code after this line


System.out.print("Enter an integer, x: ");
 int x =IO.inputInt();


System.out.print("Enter an integer, y: ");
 int y = IO.inputInt();
System.out.print("Answer = "+ (x*y));
 }
}
```

And what does these errors mean?

[ERROR] cannot find symbol, symbol: method inputInt(), location: class comp102x.IO.

[ERROR] cannot find symbol, symbol: method inputInt(), location: class comp102x.IO.

Comment: I don't know about the comp102x package. But I suggest you to use the scanner or other similar class for input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791998/bluej-import102x-io

Comment: Panther Coder: 
I tried to use the scanner class, but doesn't work 
I am doing an online course and I don't how user input in that way..

Comment: I solved it.
Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

How about using Scanner?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        multiply();
    }

    public static void multiply() {
        // Please write your code after this line
        Scanner IO = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter an integer, x: ");
        int x = IO.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter an integer, y: ");
        int y = IO.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Answer = " + (x * y));

        IO.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a function (method)
inputInt()
which  you haven't defined anywhere or isn't present in the import class which you have used , this what the error is trying to tell you.